# How to make normal user remote to Windows 2016 by powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm trying following powershell script to remowe to windows 2016.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $password )
enter-pssession -computername 192.168.xxx.xxx -credential $cred
```

When login with user that has "Adminstrators" permission, it works just fine, but when login with user that only has "Users" permission, it gets access is denied error.

So, What should I do to make "Users" to login with powershell?

---

OK, I follow the guide below

https://www.sevecek.com/EnglishPages/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=f6e49214-a43d-4fa5-9537-fb46eabe0cb8&ID=4&Web=6dbd0194-ad16-4838-ad08-7f33e3009473

And I can remote Windows Server 2016 with normal user.
But when I tried following script, the exception happens again.

```
[192.168.XXX.XXX]: PS C:\Users\TestUser\Documents> ([ADSI] "WinNT://localhost/TestUser,user").ChangePassword("#EDC4rfv", "1qaz@WSX")
```

And the error message is

```
Exception calling "ChangePassword" with "2" argument(s): "Access is denied.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ ([ADSI] "WinNT://localhost/TestUser,user").ChangePassword("#EDC4rfv", " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Does that mean even normal user can remote to Windows Server 2016, they still can't run commands?

Comment: In order to make it easier for people to help you I recommend you to edit your question to include the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

To use PowerShell remoting(default endpoint "Microsoft.PowerShell"), the user should be part of Administrators group in remote machine.

You can tackle this by creating an Endpoint and giving the normal user permission to access it on the remote machine.

More about it is in below link.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/31/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/